# /etc/group: why the username does not appear in its own primary group?

Tags: users, user-management, groups

According with many tutorials in the `/etc/group` file is listed all the groups.

Through the `cat /etc/group | grep omicron` command (*omicron* is the default custom user created in the Linux installation) appears:

```
adm:x:4:syslog,omicron
cdrom:x:24:omicron
sudo:x:27:omicron
dip:x:30:omicron
plugdev:x:46:omicron
lpadmin:x:120:omicron
lxd:x:132:omicron
omicron:x:1000:
sambashare:x:133:omicron
```

According with the output I can understand that each line represents:

- The group name
- The `X` represents something about password or some protection
- The `gid` is the id of the group
- Finally what users are assigned to the group.

What is not clear for me:

- why appears `omicron:x:1000:` and not `omicron:x:1000:omicron`?

The `omicron` user has its primary group `omicron` too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A user doesn't need to be listed as the member of a group in `/etc/group` if that group is their primary group. That's just how it is and has been for decades. Some user management tools do explicitly put the user in the `/etc/group` list, but not all.